# Add chat-like YouTube support to Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, videos

Some Stack Exchange sites, like Super User and Gaming, would derive large benefits from having some sort of YouTube integration.

I'm not suggesting having embedded players in pages. Rather, I'm thinking of the kind of support chat has: a static video snapshot, with a play symbol overlay.

The suggested syntax is an extension of the linking one:

```
[Rickroll][1!]

  [1!]: http://youtu.be/EK2tWVj6lXw
```

Standard markdown parsers will ignore the exclamation point inside the link name and simply fall back on displaying a plain vanilla text link. The short URL is used to simplify parsing (optional) and can be extended to a full URL (which then allows you to do all sorts of neighborly things like passing the appropriate `feature` parameter).

*I'm mentioning YouTube specifically because other sites, like Vimeo, restrict gaming videos or application recordings. Other SE sites, like the upcoming Graphic Design, could do with additional sites, however.*

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers) as this one does not suggest using <object> or <video> tags.

Comment: I'm all for it, Gaming needs more gameplay video's!

Comment: I'm all for it, I think this would be great for a lot of sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

YouTube links will be auto-converted to videos on a per-site basis.

We have experimentally enabled this on gaming.se for now.

Comment: Does it automagically convert? Because it doesn't seem to work [on the other YouTube links on the Angry Birds question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3748/10)

Comment: You may want to keep the link for those users/devices that do not have Flash...

Comment: @ivo it will if you edit and save those posts. This happens at save time not view time.

Comment: If you don't have Flash, how are you going to watch the video @badp? Or would you even want to?

Comment: @Ivo There are YouTube applications for mobiles without Flash for example.

Comment: Have you tested how they respond to the link? @badp It works fine on Android (2.3) and iOS (iPad), so if you can't play YouTube links here, you'll have problems everywhere.

Comment: @Ivo There's just no link to click on there.

Comment: What are the requirements to get this on a new SE site?

Comment: Can we get this over on DSP and AVP as well?  It would seem they make a lot of sense there as well.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here's a simple application I've created to do this: **[Video Link Generator](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/XdUBf/12/embedded/result)**. Give it a try and tell me how well it works. If it works reasonably well I think I'll bake it into a userscript.

**Input:**

```
URL: http://youtu.be/EK2tWVj6lXw
Title: Rickroll
```

**Code Geneated:**

```
[![Rickroll](http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/EK2tWVj6lXw/hqdefault.jpg "Rickroll")](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EK2tWVj6lXw)
```

**Output:**

[image: Rickroll]

**Supported URL Formats:**

- YouTube

  - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[id]
  - http://youtu.be/[id]
- Vimeo

  - http://vimeo.com/[id]
  - http://vimeo.com/channels/[name]#[id]
  - http://vimeo.com/groups/[name]/videos/[id]

Comment: +1 works quite well so far.