# When doing Youtube integration, please give an alternative for devices without Flash player

Tags: feature-request, videos

Youtube integration works well, IMHO. For example, where I had to show a few screenshots of the particular bit of a game I had trouble with ([before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/17491/revisions#rev3b9c9122-541e-4f00-b3e6-24ba20d88532)), now I can just use a video ([after](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/how-to-get-past-the-section-with-revolving-lines-of-dots-in-transition)):

> [image: With flash]

There's a problem, however, and it's with devices that have no Flash. On those devices, the embedded video simply disappears:

> [image: Without flash]
>
> On my actual device, actually, the "ghost" window doesn't appear at all; there's just some vertical space where the video should have been.

Flash-less mobiles, however, are perfectly capable of playing Youtube videos — I just have to follow a link to the relevant Youtube page. (This is, among other reasons, why my [original proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71234/add-chat-like-youtube-support-to-stack-exchange) didn't go as far as actually asking for Youtube embedding.)

Is there a way the embedded video block can be replaced with... something else, when Flash is not available? Even just a bare link would do.

Comment: Lynx should be enough for anybody.

Comment: @Adam I'm sure Lynx and cvlc can team up, for great justice.

Comment: [Hello gentlemen.  All your H.264 are belong to us.](http://www.planettribes.com/allyourbase/video1_ayb.swf)

Comment: @Adam [cvlc is never gonna give you up.](http://i.imgur.com/0W9Xk.png)