# Are answers with YouTube videos a good idea?

Tags: discussion, answers

There are quite a few answers out there which are linking against YouTube-Videos for solutions.

I see several problems with it:

- Might not be work-safe, due to sound and/or corporate filters.
- Might be unsafe, because sometimes the `Overlays` of the videos are containing 'questionable' content at best (`Make over $ 5.000 in one month!`).
- It's harder to determine with a few glances if it is a fitting solution.

My question is now, is it a good thing to link against videos?

**Edit:** I quickly wrote [this OData-Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1295/find-youtube-videos-in-answers) which will fetch every answer with a youtube-link and sort it by score. This does return quite a few more answers than I believed I was talking about.

**Edit2:** As pointed out by Jeff (and as I later realized) the interesting posts are the short ones, not that by score.

> ***Related:** [Provide a way to embed videos in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers)*

Comment: You've seen "quite a few" such answers? I haven't seen *any*. No, I don't think this is a good idea at all. Links?

Comment: Do you mean specifically for Stack Overflow, or for the Stack Exchange Network in general? On Gaming, we make heavy use of them and [even got this request approved as a result](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71234/add-chat-like-youtube-support-to-stack-exchange), so I'm a bit opposed to going against them network-wide. But for Stack Overflow only? I can't even figure why you'd link a video in the first place, haha~

Comment: @Grace Note, @Cody Gray: I was mainly speaking about the trilogy, especially SU, but I think I've also seen some on SO. I can't say anything about SF because I'm not often over there.

Comment: @Grace: Well if the question is "How do I concisely implement Conway's Game of Life in APL" there really is no better answer than [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4).

Comment: @Grace Note, @Cody Gray: Please see my edit, I wrote an OData-Query which is fetching all answers with links against YouTube Videos...it's returning ~2,000 answers...way more than I believed I was talking about. :/

Comment: @Grace Note: And yes, I agree that this is actually useful for Gaming (and maybe other sites, too). But it itches a little to see them on SO/SU/SF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are referring to answers that just contain a link to a YouTube video, then I think they should be considered as any other answer that just contains a link. Answers that just contain a link are normally not considered answers. They could be answers if the OP is specifically asking for a link (to documentation, to a language module, etc). In that case, the question is probably going to be closed as not constructive.

If the answer explains what to do, and uses the video as reference, I think the link is fine.
I cannot think of answers on Stack Overflow that need a video, but I imagine in some cases they could be useful. I am not sure of the reason to choose link to a video instead of a link to a blog page, though; I would rather a link to a blog page containing a link to a video would be more appropriate, but that could not be true, depending on the question being asked.

In any case, I think it would be a courtesy to report that the link is a YouTube link, to allow users who are not in the right place to see it to follow the link when they can.

Answer (score 9):

Your query is kind of useless, IMO, because what you want is the *shortest* posts that link to YouTube.

In the context of a larger post, a YouTube link could be perfectly relevant.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1297/find-shortest-youtube-videos-in-answers

Comment: And then I suspect a mod can go through deleting most of those answers... The chances that a single link to a YouTube video is actually a good answer seem relatively slim.

Comment: Yes, I agree...I realized that after I thought about my edit.