# Is there any way I could embed a video in my question?

Tags: support, questions, videos

We can do it with images but what if I want to illustrate something with a video. Can I place a video file in the body of my question somehow or only hyperlinking is the way?

Comment: I want this feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, embedding videos is not supported (except for possibly animated GIFs). Linking is your only option.

Comment: this is supported on a site by site basis. It's only enabled on gaming right now as far as I can remember.

Comment: @Jeff Isn't that just for YouTube videos, not arbitrary anywhere videos, though?

Comment: Jeff is referring to [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66397/131713).