# Can a video be attached to an SO question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, videos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way I could embed a video in my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/is-there-any-way-i-could-embed-a-video-in-my-question)

How can I attach a video to a Stack Overflow question to better show what's happening and what the end result that I am looking for is?

Comment: This belongs on meta, but you know you can always link to things. Not sure if I'd really click on a video link though TBH; I'd lean toward using an animated gif instead where animation is necessary.

Comment: Keep in mind that when posting a question or answer it should be self-sufficient.  You shouldn't be dependent on external links for the post to be useful.  Linking to a video is fine, but you shouldn't *just* link to a video.  The question should be answerable even if the link breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Post your video to youtube and make it only visible by Link, then post it here

Answer (score 1):

Even if Stack Overflow supported embedding videos, It would probably be more appropriate to just post a link to the video anyway.

Imagine opening a question, and then being presented with a large embedded video.  It's obnoxious, and pulls attention away from the rest of the problem description.

Comment: Not to mention it slows down the page load. I **can't stand** when I load a page that has a bunch of embedded videos and I have to sit there and wait for them to all load before my page works properly...

Answer (score 0):

upload to youtube and provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Just post a link to the Video hosted on some website like youtube or vimeo