# Can I add a YouTube video to my answer in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, answers, videos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide a way to embed videos in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers)

Is it possible to add a video in the answers on Stack Overflow?

I think I saw this in some answers a few months ago, but how do they do it?

Do I need an special tag?

Comment: you could use [https://gifs.com/](https://gifs.com/) as described [here](https://www.computerhope.com/tips/tip219.htm) and used [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198472/top-ubuntu-download-manager-with-bandwidth-limiter-and?noredirect=1#comment2011578_1198472)

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot embed videos in posts.

You can [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ) to YouTube video pages if you wish. Though I urge you to consider if such a link is really necessary. We like to keep answers on SO as self-contained as possible.

Comment: You can on [gaming.se], though.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3749/481).

Comment: Self contained and elaborate. So, wouldn't it make more sense if an answer can be demonstrated with a simple example in action and screen recording youtube vid and including it in the answer inline and not just as a link (Along with the explanation text)?

Comment: A video can explaing better than typing in some contexts, although typing will make the question or answer indexed by searching engines. A combination of both could be an option.

Comment: I tried making a tortal video and posting it with a description. It has been deleted. It probally looks like spam.