# Allow embedded HTML5 YouTube video

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, youtube

Currently, this site embeds YouTube videos as Flash. (see an example: [How to unlock the achievements related to hidden areas  in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/hidden-areas-in-portal-2-single-player-campaign))

However, this is not the best solution, as now YouTube also supports HTML5, and some users (like me!) prefer to use HTML5 player instead of Flash. Supposedly, it should also work on devices that don't have Flash player (I can't confirm because I don't have one).

The solution seems quite simple: just change the embed code to an `iframe`, as described at [A New Way To Embed YouTube Videos](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html)

---

EDIT: [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#AS3_Object_Embeds) says:

> Note: YouTube `<object>` embeds were [deprecated](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/01/youtube-now-defaults-to-html5_27.html) on January 27, 2015. Please migrate your applications to the [`<iframe>` embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds), which can intelligently use whichever embedded player – HTML (`<video>`) or Flash (`<object>`) – the client supports.

Comment: Is the HTML5 player now used?

Comment: @Chipperyman: Nope, not yet. Still using the embedded flash player. Tested by opening [that link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/hidden-areas-in-portal-2-single-player-campaign) on both desktop and mobile Chrome.

Comment: Surprisingly this has never been answered...

Comment: Guess that when it breaks, this can be retagged as [tag:bug] and maybe have better chance of getting official attention. Feature requests are in the very bottom of the team's radar/list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is finally done. Quoting myself from [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/embed-youtube-videos-using-the-html5-player/10709#10709),

> All Stack Exchange sites that have either YouTube or SoundCloud embedding enabled now use the respective IFRAME embeds. In light of [recent](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/07/13/two-more-critical-flash-flaws-discovered-in-hacking-team-data-breach/) flash-related [happenings](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked/p946), we have also re-rendered all affected posts, which means that even old questions and answers that contain an embedded video will now use the HTML5 player.
>
> Bye bye, Flash.

Comment: I see the preview does not "onebox" the links, is this by design?

Comment: Sort of, yes. It has never done it. The major problem is that the preview updates with every keystroke, which means the embed would be included anew multiple times a second, which is annoying and may also cause issues when YouTube isn't happy with you making so many requests in such a short time.

Comment: Fair enough, though maybe it's better to think of some alternative... people love seeing in advance how their post is going to look like. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the improvement! This makes browsing on SE app more convenient! (comparing to the big empty space, since Flash is not supported on most mobile apps)

Answer (score 1):

This question was never answered and I also noticed the lack of support for the HTML 5 player.
I know this isn't a [status-accepted](/questions/tagged/status-accepted) but it's been 3 years.

[Here is a userscript on openuserjs.org](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/jhawins/Stackexchange_HTML_5_Youtube_Enabler) that enables this functionality by using the [Youtube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to replace the standard `embed` tags with `iframe`s.

Comment: Although that's a great workaround, it still does not solve the issue for browsers without user-scripts support (like most/all mobile browsers).

Comment: @DenilsonSá yeah... Sorry.