# Please Improve supported URLs list for Embedded YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, youtube

When I put `www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyz` format in a post, the webpage shows embedded player of YouTube (on select sites, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260734/260841) for more info). But, it doesn't show the embedded player when I use the following URL formats:

- `youtube.com/watch?v=xyz` (Ommision of www)
- `youtu.be/xyz` (The URL we get from share option of YouTube; more accessible on smartphones)

Please, embed videos on these two URL variants, too. Implementation shouldn't be difficult or time-consuming. I think it's a 5 minute job.

Comment: "I think it's a 5 minute job.". You should read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb.aspx

Comment: @Oded Ahhhhhh... But have you read the comments? *What a fantastic argument for Open Source!* :D

Comment: +1 Please also support both `http://` and `https://`, and support embedding at specific times using `?t=XX`: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273197/enable-video-embeds-that-start-at-a-specific-time

Comment: Also note that `http://youtu.be` embeds properly, but `https://youtu.be` does not

Comment: I suggest accepting [Marc Gravell's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277359/351462), since this request was completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything mentioned should be supported after the next build.

Comment: Including the timecode specific links?

Comment: @Catija I believe that was already there. I didn't check them specifically, but I'm looking at the code, at it does have some likely-looking pieces for that

Answer (score 5):

Currently only a limited subset of youtube urls are supported, with picky support for subdomains, and **inconsistent support for https and http**. Some versions require https some require http.

Per my request on MTV.meta [Please Improve Youtube URL Parsing](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/improve-youtube-url-parsing/2200#2200):

> Per a related question on MTV.Meta, [Supported URLs for video embedding](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2105/49) the currently supported ones are:
>
> ```
> http://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> ```
>
> While some unsupported ones are:
>
> ```
> https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M
> http://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> https://youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M
> ```
>
> ***The requested ones:***
>   Mobile links with the "m." subdomain
>
> - https ex:`https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
> - http
>     ex:`http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
>
> No Subdomain
>
> - https ex: `https://youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
> - http ex: `http://youtube.com/watch?v=71fWtJXEI0Q`
>
> Shortened by youtube's shortener
>
> - https ex: `https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M`

Comment: Another related Meta.SE post, specific to timecode-sensitive embeds: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273197/enable-video-embeds-that-start-at-a-specific-time