# Enable video embeds that start at a specific time

Tags: support, videos, youtube

YouTube allows you to link to a specific starting time in a video a few different ways, with time specified in the query string or fragment, as seconds or minutes and seconds. For example:

- https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M?t=110
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&start=110
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&t=1m50s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M#t=1m50

However, the resulting embed code [on sites with embedding enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/130285) doesn't incorporate that start time—in fact it appears to explicitly specify a start time of 0.

```
<div class="youtube-embed"><div>
  <iframe width="640px" height="395px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rEWaqUVac3M?start=0"></iframe>
</div></div>
```

Can the URL parser that converts YouTube links to embedded videos be changed to [preserve the start time in the embed code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#start)? This would be helpful for answers that reference a particular part of a video, particularly when it occurs well after the beginning.

---

Edit: as [Jason Baker pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273197/enable-video-embeds-that-start-at-a-specific-time#273229), this is possible if you use [the right format](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2106/26745)—in fact, the third URL in the list above actually works to embed a video at a specific starting time. However, the URLs generated by YouTube's built-in "share" features (in the box below the video on the YouTube page, or by right-clicking on the video) are generally *not* recognized by SE. So this request really is a conceptual duplicate of "[Embed YouTube videos from variant URLs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269769/embed-youtube-videos-from-variant-urls)": please support more YouTube URL format variants, in particular the ones generated by YouTube:

- Embedding videos from `https://youtu.be/<ID>`
- Recognizing start timestamps in `?t=XXX` form (time in seconds, without `m` or `s`).

Comment: Similar/related request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269769/embed-youtube-videos-from-variant-urls).

Comment: What site were you trying this on? SFF, at least, already has this. Consider my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71382/how-does-the-animus-know-which-ancestors-memories-it-should-reproduce/71389#71389), for instance

Comment: @JasonBaker That's interesting... I may be misremembering but I feel like it doesn't work on M&TV... and I just [checked it now](http://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/46420/revisions) and it does not...

Comment: @Catija Can you try it with http (instead of https)? I'd do it myself, but I don't have enough rep on M&TV

Comment: @JasonBaker Amazingly, that worked... interesting. You should consider posting that as an answer. It seems to also address the issue on the similar question I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: @Catija It seems like it's probably a bug that it only works for the one URL format, though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *does* actually work, with caveats. Specifically, embedding at a specific time works as long as the link meets the following criteria<sup>1</sup>:

- It must use either `www.youtube.com`, `youtube.com` (without the leading `www.`) or `youtu.be` as the domain. `www.youtu.be` will not embed properly
- If using the `youtu.be` domain, the time index must use the `&t=XXmYYs` format (as opposed to the `&start=XXX` format); otherwise the video will embed, but will not be time-indexed

For a working example, consider my answer to [How does the Animus know which ancestor's memories it should reproduce?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71382/how-does-the-animus-know-which-ancestors-memories-it-should-reproduce/71389#71389) on SFF.SE, where all three videos are queued to a specific time.

You can also see this in action in the [revisions to Barney Fife: “In life there are many roads…” quote?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/46420/revisions), from M&TV.SE<sup>2</sup>, where you can see that the `https` version fails to embed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to Miles for doing some more testing on this

<sup>2</sup> Thanks to Catja for testing this

Comment: @Miles Thanks for the correction; I could have sworn that didn't work for me earlier, but I must have done something wrong

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it points out that embedding with start time is possible. My (updated) request to support more URL formats is still open, but I guess now that's covered in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Support for time-specific embedding of shortened YouTube URLs was added [sometime around March 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269769/351462). You can view this for yourself on the [Movies & TV Formatting Sandbox](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3927/48480).

This includes support for:

- Timestamped (Shortened): `https://youtu.be/rEWaqUVac3M?t=110`
- Timestamped (&start=##): `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&start=110`
- Timestamped (&t=##): `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEWaqUVac3M&t=1m50s`

For more information, see *[Supported URLs for video embedding](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2105/48480)*.