# Community ads can no longer be posted because of minimum body character count

Tags: bug, status-completed, open-source-advertising

[Since post character length excludes link's alt text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130926/increase-minimum-word-count-with-links), community ads are now counted as having 0 characters in the body. There may need to be an exception in place for questions tagged with [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads).

[image: The answer in question]

Comment: It's not links that are excluded, but the image alt text.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks, yes. This was accidental, and was fixed yesterday. Normality (at least, as much as we are qualified to identify such) has been resumed.

Comment: Was the bug that it wasn't counting image alt-text, or that threads tagged community-ads weren't ignoring the character count?

Comment: @nhinkle to be specific, our character counter is looking at ***text*** now; not images, not `<!-- comments -->` etc, but *text*. Had to work around that.