# Is it possible to embed videos in questions?

Tags: support, videos

Is it possible to embed a video in my questions? If so, how can I do this?

I feel this feature would be useful when someone wants to demonstrate a phenomenon which can be captured with a screen-capture tool and saved as a file on their computer.

Currently, to do this, you have to upload the file to an external site and link to it, but this is cumbersome for both the asker and the people reading the question, further more, it requires that you have an account on some external site that makes this possible.

There is [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers) about embedding videos in answers, which gave me the feeling that you can't do it in questions either, but it wasn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: Why isn't a link to the video enough? Can you add the link to the other question that wasn't clear for you?

Comment: Because the video resides on my personal computer. It is a screen cap. I would prefer not to have to upload to some other site, which would also require me to make an account

Comment: you say "It would be very useful" but don't explain why.  why would this be useful, as I don't see a need

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Currently, you can only embed **YouTube** videos on the sites Jeff mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/260841).

You can put them on answers *and* questions. [Here's an example question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21101/who-is-the-employee-that-steve-jobs-fired) with a YouTube embed.

(The sites currently are:)

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com
- https://music.stackexchange.com
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com
- https://movies.stackexchange.com

I highly recommend using animated GIFs if you're making screencaps (rather than videos), because you can just upload them with SE's normal image uploader and they will be embedded and played normally.

If you want to share videos on other sites/from other sites, just post a link - but *make sure there is some context* — they can be removed from the site, or the link might be changed — as they are not being hosted on SE's Imgur account!

Comment: +1 The suggestion to use animated GIFs worked really well for me when I needed to put a short screen capture video up on Stackoverflow

Comment: Using a GIF didn't work that well for me since it turns out GIFs don't have sound and I have an audio problem

Comment: It would be nice for SO to offer an easy way to convert a screencapture to GIF.

Comment: I tend to use Streamable for screen capture sharing, not YouTube. I currently use Snipping Tool for the majority of my captures. I guess if MS would add .gif as an output format for Save As, going to GIF format would be a lot simpler. Surely there are better animated image formats available though. .webp?