# Extending media from photos to small video and audio

Tags: feature-request

Photos have a limit of 2 MB. Communication is greatly improved when a small  (less than 2 MB) .mov or similar file could be posted to reproduce observations for mechanics.stackexchange.com and possibly other sites.  For example, reproducing sounds often aid in the diagnosis of mechanical difficulties.

I would think it to be in the interest, if not strategic, of SE to retain custody of said assets and not cede them to YouTube or other site.

How would such a feature request to enable all media less than 2 MB be submitted?

Comment: Submitting it here would be fine, as would requesting this on Mechanics Meta. But you're probably going to need a bit more of an argument than 'it would be helpful', and explain more about what exactly would make it helpful. SoI would recommend starting with a discussion on Mechanics Meta. Is there a specific need for video uploads on that site? Is this something that could be arranged with already existing features, like [requesting youtube embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/369802) or using [animated gifs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248250/369802)? If not, why not?

Comment: Related: [Embedded audio player on language sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152282/273494)