# Edit page does not embed video

Tags: bug, youtube

One can embed videos in a SE post. However, when the page is being edited, or written, then the video is not embedded in the preview part of the page. Compare the usual presentation of the post:

> [image: SE page with embedded video]

with the preview pane of the same page in edit mode

> [image: SE page with embedded video in edit mode]

Is this as intended? After all, as Martin Smith says in [his comment below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288856/edit-page-does-not-embed-video#comment-937619), images preview correctly, and are not regarded as an obstruction.

I have tagged this as a bug as I feel that it is rather misleading to the user, as it is misrepresenting how the final post will look. However, it *could* be a feature request, I suppose.

Comment: I've had this happen, I think that it's [status-bydesign]. It makes it easier to see everything instead of having a large video in the way.

Comment: @Mithrandir images preview fine though and the same argument could be made about those.

Comment: @MartinSmith true, but video embedding is not enabled network wide, based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/158100). That probably explains why it is for now only implemented in the server side markdown parser

Comment: @rene - would you like to make an answer out of your comment (and maybe include - and expand upon Mithrandir's comment)? I'll then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Greenonline I don't think I can. The only thing I have to add is that it is not a bug but a missing feature. In my attempt to write an answer I get very close to the answer that is already there where I'm adding all kind of speculation why this works as it does. Better left to an SE Dev IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Embedding media is the result of 'post processing' that happens once the edit is done and submitted.

For media to be embedded while one was engaged in the editing process, the site would have to be able to scan the proposed changes before they were submitted, assuming there were no errors.

Comment: While I understand what you mean, images (and image links) are embedded and visible without issue, unlike video (links).