# "bumped to the homepage" is missing in mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web, bump

When a question is auto bumped to the homepage by Community, we get a notice in the full site:

> [image]

However when viewed in mobile, or just mobile theme, the notice isn't there:

> [image]

(used [this question for screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288856/edit-page-does-not-embed-video))

Can it please be added so that mobile users will also have that information available to them?